# Oracle SELECT granted but still can't access table across users

Tags: oracle, permissions, roles, sql-grant

Can any one see what's wrong with this:

User ABC:

```
create table def.something (
  id number,
  ref number references def.anotherTable(id)
);

create role ROUser;

grant select on def.something to ROUser;

grant ROUser to ghi;
```

User DEF:

```
select * from something;
...
X rows returned
```

User GHI:

```
select * from def.something;
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Is the fact that there's a foreign key, that GHI doesn't have access to, on `def.something` the problem?

---

**EDIT** I've just tried this again on another server and it works fine (i.e., as expected). Not entirely sure what's going on here, but I think it may have something to do with some error on my part... As such, I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: what happens if you do `grant select on def.something to ROUser;` as DEF?

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably running that `SELECT` statement in PL/SQL block? In PL/SQL, **privileges granted through roles are not recognized**. Try adding direct `SELECT` privilege on that table and see if it works.

Comment: Adding an explicit `grant select` does fix the problem, but the GHI example above is not being executed within a PL/SQL block: It's straight SQL.

Comment: @Xophmeister strange, I created all the objects and users and it works for me. Which database version are you using? Where are you running your queries (SQLDeveloper?)? Can you try creating another table (simplest, one numerical column) in `def` schema, grant select on it to `ROUSer` role and check if you can query it as `ghi` user?

Comment: 10gR2 through Oracle SQL Developer. Tried using a table with just one numeric column and it works as I would have expected. Also, I can't replicate the problem on a different server... As such, I think I've done something stupid, but just haven't spotted it yet! Voting to close (and thank you for your help :)

Comment: Faced the same issue, tried running the select statement via sqlplus got the output but not in SQL developer